# Populating missing date values

Tags: sql, sql-server, r

So I have a table that shows inventory values by Item ID. I need to find the number of days, and which days, each item was out of stock. My table only adds a new row each time there is a change in the inventory value, so I only have the day that any given item went out of stock, but not any accompanying days it continued to be out of stock. Here's an example of what it looks like//

```
ItemID  QTY  ADate 
10007   2   2011-07-22
10007   1   2011-07-27
10007   2   2011-09-01
10007   1   2011-09-23 
10007   2   2011-09-29 
10007   0   2011-10-29
10007   2   2011-11-03
10007   1   2011-11-21
23028   2   2011-07-23 
23028   0   2011-08-03 
23028   2   2011-08-10
```

What I'd like to have is:

```
ItemID  QTY  ADate
10007   2   2011-07-22 
10007   2   2011-07-23
10007   2   2011-07-24
10007   2   2011-07-25
10007   2   2011-07-26
10007   1   2011-07-27
10007   1   2011-07-28
10007   1   2011-07-29
10007   1   2011-07-30
```

etc...
`

Then I could grab the days, by item ID, that I was out of stock. I don't have any code to show, because frankly I don't even know where to start. Any idea how to tackle this one? Thanks so much!

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. Do you want to insert rows with "0" for every day between the value going to zero and it becoming non-zero for a given item ID?  Or do you just want a query that returns how many days a given item ID was at zero?  Or what?

Comment: Agreed. The question seems to be asking for days when items were out of stock but your desired results appear to show only the days where there was stock. That'd just be a case of `where QTY> 0`

Comment: Is the QTY inventory qty? If so, for ItemID=10007, it is out of stock between 2011-10-29 and 2011-11-03, right?

Comment: he only has the deltas but needs to fill the missing dates between the deltas

Comment: That's right, I need to fill in the missing days so I can count number of days out of stock. Right now, I only have a date entry when the inventory QTY changes. If it stays at QTY=2 for a few days, I have no entries. If it stays at QTY=0 for a week, I only have 1 entry.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want a row for every consecutive day, not just days when a change occurs. So for example ItemID 10007 has QTY = 2 on 2011-07-22, 2011-07-23, 2011-07-24...up to 2011-07-27, when it changes to 1.

In that case, try this, assuming you have a data frame in R named `mydata` and the dates are in character format:

```
library(tidyverse)
mydata %>% 
  mutate(ADate = as.Date(ADate)) %>% 
  complete(ADate = seq.Date(min(ADate), max(ADate), by = "day")) %>%
  fill(ItemID, QTY)
```

If you add `%>% filter(QTY == 0)` to the end, you should see:

```
ADate      ItemID   QTY
   <date>      <int> <int>
 1 2011-08-03  23028     0
 2 2011-08-04  23028     0
 3 2011-08-05  23028     0
 4 2011-08-06  23028     0
 5 2011-08-07  23028     0
 6 2011-08-08  23028     0
 7 2011-08-09  23028     0
 8 2011-10-29  10007     0
 9 2011-10-30  10007     0
10 2011-10-31  10007     0
11 2011-11-01  10007     0
12 2011-11-02  10007     0
```

Comment: This runs through R ok, but I'm not getting the consecutive days like you show here. Could I be doing something wrong?

Comment: My code + your example data = the output shown, on my machine.

Comment: You can try adding `%>% arrange(ADate)` to the end of the code if this issue persists.

Comment: The problem is that I gave a poor sample data set, that's my fault. It looks like when there are overlapping dates for different skus it doesn't work. For example, if I add "23028   0   2011-11-01" and "23028   1   2011-11-10" I don't get an accurate listing of days out of stock.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to fill in days with the most recent value.  One method is a recursive CTE.  But that is actually a pain.  Let me assume you have a `numbers` table:

```
select id.itemid, dateadd(day, n.n, t.min_adate) as dte, t.qty
from (select t.itemid, min(adate) as min_adate
      from t
      group by itemid
     ) id join
     numbers n
     on dateadd(day, n.n, t.min_adate) < getdate() outer apply
     (select top 1 t.*
      from t
      where t.itemid = id.itemid and t.date <= dateadd(day, n.n, t.min_adate)
      order by t.date desc
     ) t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find this demo using CTE http://rextester.com/live/CDFT20818
and a number of 2012+ functions otherwise substitute.

```
declare @mytable table (itemid int,qty int,adate date)

insert into @mytable 
values
( 10007,   2,'   2011-07-22'),
( 10007 ,  1,'   2011-07-27'),
( 10008 ,  1,'   2011-07-23'),
( 10008 ,  0,'   2011-07-16'),
( 10008 ,  4,'   2011-07-10')

declare @som date = '2011-07-01';
declare @eom date = eomonth(@som);



;with myCalendar as 
(
   Select  @som startdate
         union all
    Select dateadd(day,1,startdate) startdate
        from myCalendar
        where startdate < @eom
)
,myDistinctList as (
select t.itemid, c.startdate
  from myCalendar c
  cross join 
  (select distinct itemid from @mytable) t
), myFinal as (
select 
l.itemid,
iif(t.qty is null,(select top 1 qty from @mytable x where  x.itemid = l.itemid and x.adate <= l.startdate order by x.adate desc),t.qty) [qty],
l.startdate [adate]
from myDistinctList l
left outer join @mytable t
    on t.itemid = l.itemid
    and t.adate = l.startdate
) 
select * from myFinal 
where qty is not null
order by itemid,adate;
```

Comment: customize the calendar accordingly.. i'm pretty sure this is what you are after of.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way:

```
tmp <- split(d, d$ItemID)
f <- function(x) {
  b <- seq(min(x$ADate), max(x$ADate), "day")
  a <- do.call(c, mapply(rep, x$QTY[-nrow(x)], diff(x$ADate)))
  a <- c(a, x$QTY[nrow(x)])
  data.frame(x$ItemID[1], a, b)
}
out <- do.call(rbind, lapply(tmp, f))
rownames(out) <- NULL
colnames(out) <- c("ItemID", "QTY", "ADate")
```

**Data**

```
d <- "ItemID  QTY  ADate 
10007   2   2011-07-22
10007   1   2011-07-27
10007   2   2011-09-01
10007   1   2011-09-23 
10007   2   2011-09-29 
10007   0   2011-10-29
10007   2   2011-11-03
10007   1   2011-11-21
23028   2   2011-07-23 
23028   0   2011-08-03 
23028   2   2011-08-10"
d <- read.table(text = d,header = T)
d$ADate <- as.POSIXct(d$ADate,"UTC")
d <- d[order(d$ItemID,d$ADate),]
```

Comment: I get an error saying the second argument in do.call must be a list. Could I be doing something wrong here?

Comment: It's working fine with the example you provided.I suppose I'd need more info to help further.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate this date sequence using `LEAD` (requires sql server 2012+) and a  CTE as below

```
WITH Orders AS 
( 
  SELECT ItemID,QTY,
      LEAD (cADate, 1, NULL) OVER (ORDER BY ItemID,cADate )  AS NExtVal,
      cADate AS  Number  
  FROM Table1
  -- WHERE QTY > 0 -- remove this  if you want 
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT ItemID,QTY,NExtVal,  DATEADD(DAY, 1, Number)
  FROM Orders  
  WHERE  DATEADD(DAY, 1, Number)  < NExtVal
)     
SELECT ItemID,QTY, Number AS DateSequence FROM Orders
ORDER BY ItemID,Number
```

Here is the [Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5d099/23) to the sample code.

Answer (score 0):

A `R` solution using `tidyverse` library, Using @Brian's data:

```
date_seq <- seq(from=min(d$ADate),
            to=max(d$ADate),
            by="day")

library(tidyverse)
d %>%
  right_join(expand.grid(ItemID = unique(.$ItemID),ADate=date_seq)) %>%
  arrange(ItemID) %>%
  group_by(ItemID) %>%
  fill(ItemID,QTY) 

# # A tibble: 40 x 3
# # Groups:   ItemID [2]
#    ItemID   QTY      ADate
#     <int> <int>     <dttm>
#  1  10007     2 2011-07-22
#  2  10007     2 2011-07-23
#  3  10007     2 2011-07-24
#  4  10007     2 2011-07-25
#  5  10007     2 2011-07-26
#  6  10007     1 2011-07-27
#  7  10007     1 2011-07-28
#  8  10007     1 2011-07-29
#  9  10007     1 2011-07-30
# 10  10007     1 2011-07-31
# # ... with 30 more rows
```